# D3js - Trying to update links in a Force Layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'd like to update links and nodes of a force directed layout at run-time. But the behavior is strange, because sometimes it does not add new links and sometimes it does not remove old links. Do you have any suggestions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

**network.js**

```
// Network View size
var width = 1280,
height = 500

var radius = 200;
var robj   = 8;
var scaled_radius = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 7000000000000])
  .range([10, 40]);

var svg_network = d3.select(document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, "svg"))
                  .attr("width", width)
                  .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(1.0)
    .distance(100)
    .charge(-60)
    .size([width, height]);

var timestamp_info = svg_network.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 10)
      .attr("dy", 10);

function graph_network_start(flowz) 
{
  /* ------------------------ */
  /* DATA PREPROCESSING       */
  /* ------------------------ */

  flowz = network_preprocess(flowz) 

  /* ------------------------ */
  /* NODE POSITIONING         */
  /* ------------------------ */

  nodePositioning(flowz.activeNodes);
  var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, flowz.activeNodes.length]).range([0, 180]);

  // Bind link and node data to DOM elements
  var link = svg_network.selectAll(".link").data(flowz.flow, function(d) { return d.source + "-" + d.target;  });
  var node = svg_network.selectAll("g.node").data(flowz.activeNodes)//, function(d,i) {return i;});  

  /* ------------------------ */
  /*  UPDATE LINKS            */
  /* ------------------------ */
  link.exit().transition().duration(10).remove();

  link.enter().append("line")
    .attr("id",function(d){return d.source.ID + "-" + d.target.ID;})
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("opacity",0)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .style("opacity",1);

  /* ------------------------ */
  /*  UPDATE NODES            */
  /* ------------------------ */

  node.exit().transition().duration(100).remove();

  var newNode = node.enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("id", function(d) {return d.ID})
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag).on("click", function(d){
    if (nodes[d.ID].name == "Workstations Site 1") {
        selectedSite=1; bubble_visualize(selectedTimestamp, selectedSite);showMode(2);
    } else if (nodes[d.ID].name == "Workstations Site 2") {
        selectedSite=2; bubble_visualize(selectedTimestamp, selectedSite);showMode(2);
    } else if (nodes[d.ID].name == "Workstations Site 3") {
        selectedSite=3; bubble_visualize(selectedTimestamp, selectedSite);showMode(2);
    }})
    .on("mouseover", fade(.1)).on("mouseout", fade(1))

  newNode.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 8) //function(d){return scaled_radius(d.output)})
      .style("fill", color)
      .style("stroke", "black" )
      .style("opacity",0)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("opacity",1);

  newNode.append("text")
      .attr("dx", robj + 2)
      .attr("dy", ".1em")
      .text(function(d) { return nodes[d.ID].name })
      .style("opacity",0)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("opacity",1);
//if (nodes[d.ID].name == "Workstations Site" || nodes[d.ID].name == "Workstations Site 2" || nodes[d.ID].name == "Workstations Site 3") return nodes[d.ID].name });

  /* ------------------------ */
  /*  UPDATE INFOS            */
  /* ------------------------ */
  timestamp_info.text(function(d) { return new Date(flowz.timestamp).toString()});

  force
    .nodes(flowz.activeNodes)
    .links(flowz.flow)
    .on("tick", tick);
  force.start();

  var linkedByIndex = {};
  flowz.flow.forEach(function(d) {
      linkedByIndex[d.source + "," + d.target] = 1;
  });

  function color(d){
    return "steelblue"
  }

  function isConnected(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index] || a.index == b.index;
  }

  function tick()
  {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  }

  function fade(opacity) {
    return function(d) {
        node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
            this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
            return thisOpacity;
        });

        link.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
            return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
        });
    };
  }

  function nodePositioning(nodesparam){
    for (var i=0; i<nodesparam.length; i++)
    {
      if(nodes[nodesparam[i].ID].name == "Internet")
      {
        nodesparam[i].x=width/2;
        nodesparam[i].y=30;
      }
      else if (nodes[nodesparam[i].ID].name == "Firewall")
      {
        nodesparam[i].x=width/2;
        nodesparam[i].y=50;
      }
      else if (nodes[nodesparam[i].ID].name == "172.0.0.1")
      {
        nodesparam[i].x=width/2;
        nodesparam[i].y=120;
      }

      else
      {
        nodesparam[i].x = width/2 + (radius - robj) * Math.cos(Math.PI + i * (Math.PI / nodesparam.length +1)) ;
        nodesparam[i].y = height/2 + (radius - robj) * Math.sin(Math.PI + i * (Math.PI / nodesparam.length +1)) ;
      }
      nodesparam[i].fixed = true;
    }
  }

  function positionX(node, index)
  {
    if(node.name == "Internet" || node.name == "Firewall" || node.name == "127.0.0.1")
    {
        return width/2;
    }
    else
    {
        return (width/2 + (radius - robj) * Math.cos(Math.PI + index * (Math.PI / nodes.length +1))) ;
    }
  }

  function positionY(node, index)
  {
      if(node.name == "Internet")
      {
        return 30;
      }
      else if (node.name == "Firewall")
      {
        return 50;
      }
      else if (node.name == "172.0.0.1")
      {
        return 120;
      }
      else
      {
        return (height/2 + (radius - robj) * Math.sin(Math.PI + index * (Math.PI / nodes.length + 1))) ;;
      }
  }

  function network_preprocess(flowz){
    for(var i=+0; i<flowz.flow.length;i++)
    {
      for(var j=0; j<flowz.activeNodes.length;j++)
      {
        if(flowz.activeNodes[j].ID == flowz.flow[i].source)
          flowz.flow[i].source = j;
        if(flowz.activeNodes[j].ID == flowz.flow[i].target)
          flowz.flow[i].target = j;
      }     
    }
    return flowz
  }
}
```

**links.json excerpt**

```
[
  {
  "timestamp": 1364795760000,
  "flow": [
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 1,
      "value": 15540
    }
  ],
  "activeNodes": [
    {
      "output": 15540,
      "ID": 0
    },
    {
      "output": 0,
      "ID": 1
    }
  ]
},
{
  "timestamp": 1364795880000,
  "flow": [
    {
      "source": 2,
      "target": 1,
      "value": 2960
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 1,
      "value": 14800
    }
  ],
  "activeNodes": [
    {
      "output": 14800,
      "ID": 0
    },
    {
      "output": 0,
      "ID": 1
    },
    {
      "output": 2960,
      "ID": 2
    }
  ]
}
]
```

**EDIT: 1**
I could narrow it down. The links.source and links.target elements are being destroyed by my code. For some reason they are changed from int to objects:

Output at time[0]:

```
Object {source: 3, target: 4, value: 213143231}
Object {source: 5, target: 4, value: 448560}
```

and when I go to another dataset and back to time[0]:

```
Object {source: Object, target: Object, value: "213143231"}
Object {source: Object, target: Object, value: "448560"}
```

Even the values get changed into strings. Maybe it happens inside of this code excerpt:

```
function graph_network_start(flowz) 
{
flowz = network_preprocess(flowz);
...
var link = svg_network.selectAll(".link").data(flowz.flow, function(d) { console.log(d);   return d.source + "-" + d.target;  });
var node = svg_network.selectAll("g.node").data(flowz.activeNodes, function(d) {return d.ID})  
...
force
.nodes(flowz.activeNodes)
.links(flowz.flow)
.on("tick", tick);
force.start();


function network_preprocess(flowz){
  /* 
    We have to remove not existing nodes and add new nodes to our network nodes
  */ 

  // Remove every node which does not exist anymore
  var activeSet = new HashSet();
  activeSet.addAll(flowz.activeNodes);
  var toRemove = network_nodes.complement(activeSet).values();
  for(var i=0; i<toRemove.length; i++)
  {
    network_nodes.remove(toRemove[i]);
  }

  // Add new nodes
  var activenodes = flowz.activeNodes;
  for(var i=0; i<activenodes.length; i++)
  {
    if (! network_nodes.contains(activenodes[i]) )
    {
      network_nodes.add(activenodes[i])
    }
  }

  // Order nodes
  var ufzuffu = network_nodes.values();
  ufzuffu.sort(function(a,b){
    var keya = a.ID;
    var keyb = b.ID;
    if(keya < keyb) return -1;
    if(keya > keyb) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
  flowz.activeNodes = ufzuffu;
  // Edit links
  for(var i=0; i<flowz.flow.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0; j<flowz.activeNodes.length;j++)
    {
      if(flowz.activeNodes[j].ID == flowz.flow[i].source)
      {
          flowz.flow[i].source = +j;
          continue;
      }
      if(flowz.activeNodes[j].ID == flowz.flow[i].target)
      {
        flowz.flow[i].target = +j;
      }
    }     
  }
    return flowz
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Well .. looks like I found a workaround:

```
var link = svg_network.selectAll(".link").data(flowz.flow, function(d) { 
    if(d.source.hasOwnProperty("ID"))
      return d.source.index + "-" + d.target.index;
    else
      return d.source + "-" + d.target;
      });
```

It works but I still dont know why it randomly(?) generates objects out of integers ..

Comment: Matching of data to DOM elements? Have you tried using a key function when calling `.data()` for the nodes?

Comment: like this:
var node = svg_network.selectAll("g.node").data(flowz.activeNodes, function(d) {return d.ID};) ? This is something I tried, but it did not help

Comment: You're using transitions for enter and exit.  If your updates come too frequently, or if "tick" or another event starts a different transition, then the enter/exit transitions will be interrupted before they can complete.  Try the code without those transitions and see if it works normally.  If so, you will need to add extra checks to avoid the transition problems.

Comment: Even removing the transitions did not work for me. However, if I start the force layout with flow[i], update the data to flow[j] and go back to flow[i] it does not draw links which have been initially there.

Comment: Could you provide a complete working example that demonstrates the problem please?